# Android create edit text animation like Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-animation, material-design

Chrome recently updated on Android. I believe to version 38 maybe?

The new tab search box translates into the Url Address box. I'm not quite sure how it does this.

This was a couple version older but found a post from: http://www.omgchrome.com/google-chrome-android-material-design-beta/ describing the details behind it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvVGc.gif

Any help would be appreciated. And I know this isn't an L Preview only thing, because its currently my production version of Chrome running on the latest version of KitKat 4.4.4.

Answer (score 3):

From my observation, I might only give you idea what is used and idea about the math

Search `EditText` is set below the Google logo, both of them are wrapped inside some `ScrollView`, probably kind of `ObservableScrollView`.

Shrinking and lengthening of `EditText` is done by the amount of pixels (percentage) scrolled with respect to the Google Logo. Hence, is the logo faded-out/in.

Lengthening and shrinking is changing its `right` coordinate.

When the logo view is off screen, the EditText is set as custom view in the actionbar.

Returning to appropriate place is probably done if the logo is scrolled >= 50% it returns to the `ActionBar/Toolbar`, otherwise it is returned to its starting position.

Worth mentioning is that the `EditText` is not clickable during the scroll, so it could be `ViewOverlay` just for animating purposes. 
I'm just doing the guesswork here.

Also do some reading on monitoring the scrollviews for such purposes [here](http://goo.gl/O9h5I).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the detailed response. I'll see what else people have to say about it. I'm sure with Material animations it might become a simple code liner, but interested too see other ways too.

Comment: Although your answer might work... I think the real way they do it, is using the new Toolbar class and then at a certain scoll point set it as the action bar..

Comment: Yes, `Toolbar` will work as parent for the `EditText`. Edited the answer.

Comment: unaccepting your answer to see if actual coded methods can be given as an answer.